# How do i mention Additional Class path in WAS 9 under ibm-web-ext.xml file

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere

in WAS7 we used to have this property in `ibm-web-ext.xmi` file

```
additionalClassPath="path of the property files"
```

How do i set the same addional class path paramter in WAS 9 ibm-web-ext.xml

Comment: This site says that additionalClassPath was deprecated. http://www.setgetweb.com/p/WAS51/wasinfo1/aes/javadoc/wccm/webappext/WebAppExtension.html
The new schema is found in the installation: <WAS_HOME>/properties/schemas/ibm-web-ext_1_1.xsd
It does not include "additionalClassPath"
What type of resource are you trying to access outside of WEB-INF?

Comment: We have property files that gets deployed to a different location out side of web-inf, These property files vary based on the environment (dev/test/uat/prod). We refer the path of these files in Additional Classpath. Any Idea how can I continue keeping the property files in a seperate folder and do not make it as a JVM property rather i want to mention something in the war level so it will only refer the folder which is specific to that particular war.